# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver - Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I am using Spring Cloud Data Flow and Spring Batch example. In this example, as [per this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-rdbms), I started Spring Cloud Data Flow Server using below command

> java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar   -->spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --spring.datasource.username=root    --?spring.datasource.password=root --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver &

[image]

But `Spring Batch` code I used only uses the `MySQL` and fully developed using it.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

When I created the Task in SCDF UI and execute the Tasks, its giving me below error -

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:222) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:174) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:85) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

JobConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> customerPagingItemReader(){
        // reading database records using JDBC in a paging fashion
        JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        reader.setFetchSize(1000);
        reader.setRowMapper(new CustomerRowMapper());

        // Sort Keys
        Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();
        sortKeys.put("id", Order.ASCENDING);

        // MySQL implementation of a PagingQueryProvider using database specific features.
        MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
        queryProvider.setSelectClause("id, firstName, lastName, birthdate");
        queryProvider.setFromClause("from customer");
        queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

        reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);

        return reader;
    }


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Customer> jsonItemWriter() throws Exception{
        String customerOutputPath = File.createTempFile("customerOutput", ".out").getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(">> Output Path = "+customerOutputPath);

        FlatFileItemWriter<Customer> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setLineAggregator(new CustomLineAggregator());
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(customerOutputPath));
        writer.afterPropertiesSet();

        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public StaxEventItemWriter<Customer> xmlItemWriter() throws Exception{
        String customerOutputPath = File.createTempFile("customerOutput", ".out").getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(">> Output Path = "+customerOutputPath);

        Map<String, Class> aliases = new HashMap<>();
        aliases.put("customer", Customer.class);

        XStreamMarshaller marshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        marshaller.setAliases(aliases);

        // StAX and Marshaller for serializing object to XML. 
        StaxEventItemWriter<Customer> writer = new StaxEventItemWriter<>();
        writer.setRootTagName("customers");
        writer.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(customerOutputPath));
        writer.afterPropertiesSet();

        return writer;
    }


    @Bean
    public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Customer> classifierCustomerCompositeItemWriter() throws Exception{
        ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Customer> compositeItemWriter = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<>();
        compositeItemWriter.setClassifier(new CustomerClassifier(xmlItemWriter(), jsonItemWriter()));

        return compositeItemWriter;
    }


    @Bean
    public Step step1() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Customer, Customer> chunk(10)
                .reader(customerPagingItemReader())
                .writer(classifierCustomerCompositeItemWriter())
                .stream(xmlItemWriter())
                .stream(jsonItemWriter())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1())
                .build();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>classifierWrittingMultipleDestinations</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>classifierWrittingMultipleDestinations</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring OXM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Note - **MySQL version is 8.0.18**

Comment: Please, share also your Gradle or Maven dependency list.  Looks like MariaDB driver is missing.

Comment: @ish - Added the whole pom.xml for reference

Comment: This question has been [cross-posted](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3887) to the project bugs tracker. It is worth checking to see if this is permitted in bug trackers - most faults are just down to misconfiguration, and the only things that should go in bug trackers are bugs that have passed triage.

Comment: Can you try with the latest release of Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Comment: Sure, do you've sample example to refer. Are you able to reproduced the same issue ?

Comment: Just want to make sure that we are using the latest and greatest.

Comment: 1.7.4 is an EOL release. Please switch to a supported version and re-attempt to use MariaDB with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use the MySQL JDBC driver in your batch app, I assume you use the same MySQL database for SCDF server as well. In this case, you need to set the MySQL driver class for spring datasource driver class name property when starting the SCDF server.

PS: I see you have created multiple SO questions and Github for a similar set of questions. Please avoid doing so in future and give it some time before you start a whole new question/issue.

Comment: The advice here is very good advice - software maintainers are pretty busy people, and cross-posting questions is just an annoyance. (The advice probably does not belong in answers though, since it is not of use to the general reader. But it is good to add it as a comment under the question).